# Postgres Sql : Alter table

Tags: java, postgresql, apache-poi

I am fetching all the records from the Excel sheet and adding columns into the database according to the Excel header row. After fetching I alter the table and adding columns into the newly created table and it works perfectly fine. but when I add one more column into the excel file and running the query again it supposed to add the column which I have created in the excel file but instead, it gives me an error of `Column already exists`
The query which I m running is

> "ALTER TABLE " + name + " ADD " + cellValue + " varchar(5000)"

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create only columns that don't exist write your query like this

```
"ALTER TABLE " + name + " ADD if not exists " + cellValue + " varchar(5000)"
```